# AWS Lambda python to get cloudwatch alarm info to trigger an alert to MS teams

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have setup few cloud watch alarms, when ever alarms goes off it triggers an lambda funciton. In lambda i am trying to read the json and notify it to MS team. But i was not able to get the alarm name from the json based.

Below is the json

```
{
  'Records': [
    {
      'EventSource': 'aws:sns',
      'EventVersion': '1.0',
      'EventSubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:-teams-lambda-trigger:123-971d-4f70-927e-123',
      'Sns': {
        'Type': 'Notification',
        'MessageId': '12-d0b8-5a86-8b33-123',
        'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:vip-prestogo-teams-lambda-trigger',
        'Subject': 'ALARM: "AuthenticationFailedException-was101" in Asia Pacific (Singapore)',
        'Message': '{"AlarmName":"AuthenticationFailedException-was101","AlarmDescription":"Found \\"AuthenticationFailedException\\" in 123","AWSAccountId":"123","NewStateValue":"ALARM","NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (30/08/20 07:38:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (-1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).","StateChangeTime":"2020-08-30T07:39:22.330+0000","Region":"Asia Pacific (Singapore)","AlarmArn":"arn:aws:cloudwatch:ap-southeast-1:123:alarm:AuthenticationFailedException-was101","OldStateValue":"OK","Trigger":{"MetricName":"AuthenticationFailedException-was101","Namespace":"AuthenticationFailedException-was101","StatisticType":"Statistic","Statistic":"AVERAGE","Unit":null,"Dimensions":[],"Period":60,"EvaluationPeriods":1,"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold","Threshold":-1.0,"TreatMissingData":"- TreatMissingData:                    notBreaching","EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":""}}',
        'Timestamp': '2020-08-30T07:39:22.372Z',
        'SignatureVersion': '1',
        'Signature': '123/WJa6/3saRvSsz+eDW10LZaAlR7jMhnU4jE73UM/+123/123/123/123/123+j+pjE0nldGG+123/xouonYXLkBrfRQPtr1sv/RzrIJ/kTYr3EwSkGL032HNrOeWmdGZ9D4gIJ4ir/mbnbSZV7w==',
        'SigningCertUrl': 'https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService.pem',
        'UnsubscribeUrl': 'https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:-teams-lambda-trigger:46235663-971d-4f70-927e-0a420040a154',
        'MessageAttributes': {
          
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

trying like below but failed:

```
 message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
alarm =message['AlarmName']
```

I am getting error as below:

string indices must be integers: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 15, in lambda_handler
"text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['AlarmDescription']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result that the "AlarmName" property is located in a json string. You need to parse this first so that the property can be accessed.

Use the `json.parse` function to retrieve the alarm name like the sample Lambda function below.

```
import boto3
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    message = json.loads(message)
    alarm_name = message["AlarmName"]
    print(alarm_name)
```

I tested this using the below event in Lambda

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:-teams-lambda-trigger:123-971d-4f70-927e-123",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "12-d0b8-5a86-8b33-123",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:vip-prestogo-teams-lambda-trigger",
        "Subject": "ALARM: \"AuthenticationFailedException-was101\" in Asia Pacific (Singapore)",
        "Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"AuthenticationFailedException-was101\",\"AlarmDescription\":\"Found \\\"AuthenticationFailedException\\\" in 123\",\"AWSAccountId\":\"123\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (30/08/20 07:38:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (-1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"2020-08-30T07:39:22.330+0000\",\"Region\":\"Asia Pacific (Singapore)\",\"AlarmArn\":\"arn:aws:cloudwatch:ap-southeast-1:123:alarm:AuthenticationFailedException-was101\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"AuthenticationFailedException-was101\",\"Namespace\":\"AuthenticationFailedException-was101\",\"StatisticType\":\"Statistic\",\"Statistic\":\"AVERAGE\",\"Unit\":null,\"Dimensions\":[],\"Period\":60,\"EvaluationPeriods\":1,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold\",\"Threshold\":-1.0,\"TreatMissingData\":\"- TreatMissingData:                    notBreaching\",\"EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile\":\"\"}}",
        "Timestamp": "2020-08-30T07:39:22.372Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "123/WJa6/3saRvSsz+eDW10LZaAlR7jMhnU4jE73UM/+123/123/123/123/123+j+pjE0nldGG+123/xouonYXLkBrfRQPtr1sv/RzrIJ/kTYr3EwSkGL032HNrOeWmdGZ9D4gIJ4ir/mbnbSZV7w==",
        "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService.pem",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123:-teams-lambda-trigger:46235663-971d-4f70-927e-0a420040a154",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This Lambda function output the string `AuthenticationFailedException-was101`

Answer (score 1):

Your `event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']` is **json string**, not python dictionary. You have to parse it into the dictionary, using [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json # if not already present

message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])

alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
```

Answer (score 0):

message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], your message is a string you need to convert it into dictionary. Whenever you have doubt like this you can use print(type(variable_name)). Your value of message may or may not have that particular key so you can use get() function to retrieve the value.

```
import json 
message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
alarm_name = message.get('AlarmName', None)
if alarm_name not None:
   {your action}
else:
    {some default action when key not present}
```